# af:query - change where clause

Tags: oracle-adf

In my form I have af:query based on a view.
also I have a checkbox that indicates to add or remove sql statements from the 'where clause' of the view.

for example:
my view query is 
"select * from employees where employees.kod_emp>0"
I need that in case the checkbox is checked the view will look like this:
"select * from employees where employees.kod_emp>0 **and employees.kod_dept = :dept_id**"
and when the checkbox is unchecked the view will return to the original query.

how could I implement it using the same af:query component?

Answer (score 1):

Make "autosubmit" property true for the check box and add a partial trigger.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to change the query of af:query.

Comment: Could you help me with it?